# auto quote in fwrite not working (Windows 10, R 3.3.1, data.table 1.9.7)

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, quote

Does anyone have the same problem with fwrite?
I'm using Windows R 3.3.1.

```
require(data.table)
fwrite(data.table(V1 = c("a;b", "a,b")), "test_fwrite1.csv", quote = "auto")
fread("test_fwrite1.csv")
read.csv("test_fwrite1.csv")

fwrite(data.table(V1 = c("a;b", "a,b")),
       "test_fwrite2.csv", sep = ";", quote = "auto")
fread("test_fwrite2.csv", sep = ";")
read.csv2("test_fwrite2.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quote = "auto"` is now implemented. Please install from CRAN or from development versions 1.9.8+ and there should be no further issue.

```
fwrite(data.table(V1 = c("a;b", "a,b")),
       "test_fwrite2.csv", sep = ";", quote = "auto")
fread("test_fwrite2.csv", sep = ";")
#     V1
# 1: a;b
# 2: a,b
read.csv2("test_fwrite2.csv")
#    V1
# 1 a;b
# 2 a,b
```